# Syntax error: Unexpected token in react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm new to `React` and was trying to integrate `materialui` component in sample project. And i'm facing following issue:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: ./app/Tabs.jsx: Unexpected token
     (9:8)

   7 |
   8 | export default class IconLabelTabs extends Component {
>  9 |   state = {
     |         ^
  10 |     index: 0,
  11 |   };
  12 |
```

I referred few blogs and found

```
{
    test: /.jsx?$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    query: {
      presets: ['es2015', 'react']
    }
},
```

in webpack but still facing same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you are missing the `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties` plugin.

I usually add the preset `stage-0` to have all these goodies at my disposal.

```
$ npm i -D babel-preset-stage-0
```

And in the `.babelrc` or in the `webpack` loader:

```
"presets": [
    ["es2015", { "modules": false, "loose": true }],
    "react",
    "stage-0"
  ],
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialise the state variables in constructor of a `Component`. In your case:

**./app/Tabs.jsx**

```
export default class IconLabelTabs extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {index: 0};
  }
}
```

Comment: No necessary if you are using the right babel plugin